# Access machine learning models via REST API

Tags: java, rest, machine-learning, microservices, conv-neural-network

I have made a Convolutional Neural Network to classify cats and dogs images. The dataset, as well as the code, was available online. I used **Python** as my programming language. But now I need to deploy this model on a server and need to access it using REST API.

I have saved my model using HDF5 format. example "model.h5"
For reference: **https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/**

We can convert it into PMML file as well but CNN is not supported yet by PMML file.

We can use flask library to convert the model into restful web service like this: "**https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/big-data/how-to-move-machine-learning-model-to-production/**"

But **I would prefer java.**

I prefer making a microservice using Spring Boot. But I didn't get any step by step article on how to do it.

Can anyone help me out, how can we achieve accessing model via REST API using Java. Or any other method to deploy and access using REST API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have trained the model using `Keras` I suggest you convert the model into `tensorflow` frozen model (`pb` file). You can use this [library](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow) to convert the `h5` format `keras` model to `tensorflow` `pb` model.

Once you have a ready `tensorflow` model you have many matured libraries to deploy the model. [Tensorflow-serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/) is the famous one which has many handy built-in features like having a restful output from the model, a faster parallel prediction and many more.

Here is a [post](https://medium.com/@mr.acle/exporting-deep-learning-models-from-keras-to-tensorflow-serving-7d4a6e49ce3) showing to deploy `keras` model in `tensorflow-serving`. After deploying int `tensorflow-serving` you can containerize it using `nvidia-docker` and then consume the service using any `java` `spring-boot` application.

Comment: Can you also guide me how to consume this service using java.. Any help with example or link to example would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/) to deploy deep learning models into production.

First, convert your model into the ONNX format, as you used Keras to train your model, you can use the library [keras-onnx](https://github.com/onnx/keras-onnx).

Then, you can use the [AI-Serving](https://github.com/autodeployai/ai-serving) that serves the ONNX model with both HTTP REST and gRPC endpoints. There is an example [notebook](https://github.com/autodeployai/ai-serving/blob/master/examples/AIServingMnistOnnxModel.ipynb) to show how to deploy the MNIST ONNX model using AI-Serving.